# Keep getting invalid IP via WiFi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

There is something wrong with my WiFi.
I keep getting an invalid IP via DHCP (169.254.x.x), this happens for ALL wifi connections (home, office, etc).
If I try a Local Ethernet connection via cable it works fine.

I have tried downloading the latest drivers for my wireless adapter, [resetting](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx) the TCP Stack and still have this issue.

One strange thing I notice is under Device Manager, Network Adapters I have 4 "Unknown Devices" and three "Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device". My guess is that this belongs to McAfee. Not sure if this is related or not, anyways to try to fix this I tried downloading the [NetLUIDfix.exe](http://kb.mcafee.com/agent/index?page=content&id=KB77696&cat=CORP_HOST_INTRUSION_PREVENTION_8_0&actp=LIST&showDraft=false) utility from McAfee but it didn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this annoying issue?
Thanks!!

Comment: You're not getting an IP of 169.254.x.x from your DHCP server. That is an "autoconf" IP address, your system generates that when DHCP fails. Check your DHCP server.

Comment: @terdon: of course! like i said, it happens with all wifi networks, not only my home's wifi

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes I missed that detail. Is your wifi correctly set to receive an IP via DHCP?

Comment: @terdon: correct, IP is set to Automatic as well as DNS

Comment: Is your wifi reporting it can see wireless networks to connect to? I'd also uninstall the unknown devices and the three remote NDIS devices; restart and then see what device manager reports.You could also something like a Ubuntu live CD and see if will connect via wireless - that at least should prove if the wifi card/adapter is ok

Comment: What make is your wifi card ? You could also try an external usb wifi adapter to see if the problem repeats.

Comment: So does it not even connect to your corporate environment?  If not, then get the IT guys at your company to deal with it.

Comment: @Adrian: i tried, they couldn't fix it and recommended formatting. i'm travelling in a few days so don't really have time for setting up everything again

Comment: Hrm, IT guys can be hit and miss with their abilities, but they do have the machine in front of them.  I think that there are too many variables to be able to diagnose 3rd hand.

Comment: First, what is the model of your laptop? Second, can you verify whether the driver installation package also installs more than just a driver, but also a vendor specific WiFi management software tool?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall everything to do with McAfee and Norton. I've seen many networking issues caused by these "antivirus" programs.

Comment: I can't - its a corporate laptop and i can't uninstall McAfee

Comment: McAfee bites.  See second QA [here](http://features.slashdot.org/story/13/05/07/2017203/interview-john-mcafee-answers-your-questions) as to how John McAfee responds to it being "one of the worst anti-virus products on the market" :D

Comment: @Gilbert: truth.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using some of the virtual adapters, which might be causing the problem, go to Network and Sharing Center, and try disabling the connections which are not required by you.[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a restore point, disable the non-wireless network adapters and see if that works.

If not delete the wireless adapter, do a hardware rescan to reinstall it.

If it fails, you can revert to the restore point you just made.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably either DHCP client isnt' working, or some firewall issue.

### First check if that's DHCP client:

1. open command prompt as admin

   1. click Start
   2. type cmd.exe
   3. press & release Ctrl+Shift+Enter
   4. it will ask about admin permissions. Allow.
2. type

   ```
   sc start dhcp
   ```

   and click Enter

It will either say that the service is already started (

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:
An instance of the service is already running.
```

– then it's not the problem), or will be started (then try to connect wi-fi again), or some error. If that's error, then you need to follow path of fixing you dhcp client.

### Second, firewalls

Windows firewall don't block DHCP by default, but, as you're using McAfee antivirus, it includes a firewall, which can be configured by your organization' admins to block DHCP, or can just be broken.

There is forum thread about that: https://community.mcafee.com/thread/28074

McAfee staff considered that using Windows Firewall instead of theirs is valid resolution and closed one.

So, you can leave McAfee antivirus running, but turn off its firewall (if your org admins allow): http://download.mcafee.com/products/webhelp/4/4105/GUID-6E2C3F81-4334-490A-A0C0-EABE466A5400.html

If your org admins won't allow and won't fix the issue by themselves, I guess you should complain to them.